# Python, mySQLdb: Is it possible to retrieve updated keys, after update?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I am executing an update query using `MySQLdb` and python 2.7. Is it possible to know which rows affected by retrieving all their ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of affected rows by using `cursor.rowcount`. The information which rows are affected is not available since the mysql api does not support this.

Comment: Thanks, is there any workaround? Maybe some inner select that returns all ids of the affected rows?

Comment: I think there is nothing to do with it - except just making a separate select query after the update one.